# Spring @Service logic with Builder Pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have implemented service logic using builder pattern like below in a Spring boot application.

```
 @Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements NotificationService{

    private Map<String, Object> emailTemplateContext;;
    private List<String> recipients;
    private String templateName;
    private String subjectName;
    private List<String> ccRecipients;

    public EmailServiceImpl() {
    }

    private EmailServiceImpl(String templateName, String subjectName, List<String> recipients,
            List<String> ccRecipients,
            Map<String, Object> emailTemplateContext) {
        this.emailTemplateContext = emailTemplateContext;
        this.recipients = recipients;
        this.templateName = templateName;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.ccRecipients = ccRecipients;
    }
    
    public static class EmailBuilder {

        private Map<String, Object> emailTemplateContext = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        private List<String> recipients;
        private String templateName;
        private String subjectName;
        private List<String> ccRecipients;

        public EmailBuilder withTemplateName(String templateName) {
            this.templateName = templateName;
            return this;
        }

        public EmailBuilder withSubjectName(String subjectName) {
            this.subjectName = subjectName;
            return this;
        }

        public EmailBuilder withTemplateContextValues(String key, String value) {
            this.emailTemplateContext.put(key, value);
            return this;
        }
        
        public EmailBuilder withTemplateContextValues(String key,List< String> value) {
            this.emailTemplateContext.put(key, value);
            return this;
        }

        public EmailBuilder withRecipients(List<String> recipients) {
            this.recipients = recipients;
            return this;
        }

        public EmailBuilder withCCRecipients(List<String> ccRecipients) {
            this.ccRecipients = ccRecipients;
            return this;
        }

        public EmailServiceImpl build() {
            return new EmailServiceImpl(templateName, subjectName, recipients, ccRecipients, emailTemplateContext);
        }
    }
    
    public void send() {
     // implement email send logic
    }
}
```

Then this will be injected in another class something like below

```
 public class EmailSender{
private EmailBuilder emailBuilder;
    EmailSender(EmailBuilder emailBuilder){
     this.emailBuilder=emailBuilder;
}

public void sendEmail(){
                this.emailBuilder
                .withRecipients(executionRunBO.getEmailRecipients().stream().map(email -> email.getEmail())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .withSubjectName("Reports Draft ").withTemplateName("/emails/reports.ftlh")
                .withTemplateContextValues("userName", "TestUser").build().send();

}
}
```

There are few questions related to the Builder pattern with Spring.

1. Since @service constructor is private Spring framework can not initiate the bean class.To avoid getting initialization exception i have made constructor to public but it is not the builder pattern.So how do i implement builder pattern correctly with Spring framework?
2. How do i call the EmailServiceImpl class's EmailBuilder outside from the service class? Since in my examples i have injected EmailBuilder as a constructor argument then Spring framework throws that

> required a bean of type '...EmailServiceImpl$EmailBuilder' that could
> not be found.

Please help me to clarify those things.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing a lot of functionality together here. I would make this more streamlined.

I would create a dto class `Email`, not a Spring bean.

```
public class Email {
    private Map<String, Object> emailTemplateContext;
    private List<String> recipients;
    private String templateName;
    private String subjectName;
    private List<String> ccRecipients;

    private Email(String templateName, String subjectName, List<String> recipients,
                             List<String> ccRecipients,
                             Map<String, Object> emailTemplateContext) {
        this.emailTemplateContext = emailTemplateContext;
        this.recipients = recipients;
        this.templateName = templateName;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.ccRecipients = ccRecipients;
    }

    public static class EmailBuilder {
        // your builder code, just build the Email 
    }

}
```

And then have a service to send emails.

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements NotificationService {
    
    public void sendEmail(Email email) {
        
    }

}
```

Call it like this

```
emailService.sendEmail(new Email.EmailBuilder().build());
```

There is no need to create a `@service` from the `Email` and `EmailBuilder`.